# analysing the proportion of names in a set of names. my output is incorrect. ("John") should return 0.25. and mary should be 0.5

Tags: java

my output is currently ("john") returns 0.25 and ("mary") also returns 0.25

```
public class Problem
{
private int count;
private final HashMap<String, Integer> counts;

public Problem() {
    this.counts = new HashMap<>();
}
public void addName(String name)
{
    Integer nameCount = counts.get(name);

    if (nameCount == null)
    {
        nameCount = 1;
        counts.put(name, nameCount);
                    nameCount++;
                    
    }

    nameCount++;
    count++;
}
```

this function should calculate the proportion

```
public double nameProportion(String name)
{
    return counts.get(name) / (double) count;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Problem namesCount = new Problem();

    namesCount.addName("James");
    namesCount.addName("John");
    namesCount.addName("Mary");
    namesCount.addName("Mary");
            

    System.out.println("Fraction of Johns: " + namesCount.nameProportion("John"));
    System.out.println("Fraction of Marys: " + namesCount.nameProportion("Mary"));
}
}
```

right now the output is incorrect, for some reason its not seeing the two marys as the same

Comment: Hm, is the title correct? Should Mary be 5 or 0.5?

Comment: it should be 0.5 sorry

Comment: Ok, that's clear. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive and primitive wrapper are not immutable when you do nameCount++, it doesn't change the value of key in hashmap. It create another Integer object and put the value of  nameCount +1 into that object, so the value of all key in hashmap in your code is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in your function `Problem#addName`. You are actually incrementing your `nameCount` at the end of the function, but the incremented value is lost when the function reaches the end of the block (*`nameCount` is a local variable, not a member variable)*.

The solution to this is to increment `nameCount` if it is not `null` and put that into the `counts` map, like so for example:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    Integer nameCount = counts.get(name);

    if (nameCount == null) {
        counts.put(name, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(name, ++nameCount);
    }

    count++;
}
```

If it is `null`, then simply a `1` is put into the map for the corresponding `name`.

Incrementing the `count` is fine, because that is a member variable and is saved within the created `namesCount` reference to the `Problem` object.

Answer (score 0):

You never update the `Map` if the name already exists in it. It is important to note that `Integer` objects are immutable; you can use `AtomicInteger` instead if you do not want to keep discarding previous objects. <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/AHBjAW)</sup>

```
public void addName(String name) {
    Integer nameCount = counts.get(name);
    if (nameCount == null) {
        nameCount = 1;
        counts.put(name, nameCount);
    } else {
        counts.put(name, nameCount + 1);
    }
    count++;
}
```

This can be simplified using [`Map#getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-). <sup>[Demo](https://ideone.com/9cjq1m)</sup>

```
public void addName(String name) {
    counts.put(name, counts.getOrDefault(name, 0) + 1);
    count++;
}
```